# Pyplot : space around overlay axes

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, astropy

I would like to have an overlay grid with axis labels. However, when I do this, the labels for the overlay grid overlap with the title and the colorbar.

For the moment, I have the following:

```
 from astropy.wcs import WCS
 from astropy.io import fits
 from astropy.utils.data import get_pkg_data_filename
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

 image_file = get_pkg_data_filename('tutorials/FITS-images/HorseHead.fits')
 hdu = fits.open(image_file)[0]
 wcs = WCS(hdu.header)

 ax = plt.subplot(projection=wcs)
 im = ax.imshow(hdu.data, origin='lower')

 overlay = ax.get_coords_overlay('galactic')
 overlay.grid(color='black', ls='dotted')
 overlay[0].set_axislabel('Galactic Longitude')
 overlay[1].set_axislabel('Galactic Latitude')

 plt.colorbar(im)
 plt.title("Horsehead nebula")
 plt.show()
```

But here, the colorbar overlaps with the right-hand side label and the title ends up under the upper label. How do I get the elements in this figure to be properly spaced ?

Is there a function that would do the opposite of `plt.tight_layout()` ?

---

I would rather not have to fumble around setting the values of the spacing by hand. I want the spacing to be done based on the size of the different elements.

For instance, I know I can do `fig.colorbar(im, pad=padvalue)`, but I want the value for `padvalue` to be found automatically.

Comment: If overlay is implimented as child artists of ax, then constrained_layout should put the colorbar to the right of all children in the axes.

Answer (score 1):

`constrained_layout` should put the colorbar to the right of any children artists of `ax1`.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0, 10, num=100)
y = x ** 2 + 10 * np.random.randn(100)

f, ax1 = plt.subplots(1,1,figsize=(6,4),
        constrained_layout=True)
im1 = ax1.scatter(x, y*1000, c=y, cmap='magma')
ax1.yaxis.tick_right()
f.colorbar(im1, ax=ax1)
```

[image]

Comment: `plt.subplots(constrained_layout=True)` gives me `TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'constrained_layout'`

Comment: You need matplotlib >= 2.2.